# Nginx returns old HTTP responses

Tags: nginx, caching, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having an issue where **Nginx** does cache some HTTP responses. I don't know why? I have installed **Nginx** on Ubuntu 18.04 and never changeed any cofig from ***nginx.conf*** file

I am serving a **Flask** application works with **MySQL** and what is happening is the when I go to the website and delete a record from a table and refresh the page the record still there. but after multiple requests the record goes away. however after multiple request the record appears again even though when I checked the database the record is not there and it is deleted successfully!

Therefore, apparently **Nginx** is returning old HTTP responses from old HTTP requests for no reasons and sometimes it does actually return fresh/correct HTTP responses

Note that guys when I run my Flask server standalone without Nginx This issue is longer there.

I also checked the Flask logs in realtime and sometime when I request something from the database, Nginx returns a response without even sending the request to Flask. So I can actually see no request being sent to Flask even though i still get a response and it always has old data

so it is definitely **Nginx** what causing it

***nginx.conf (File)***

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile off;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 6500;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

I am also using uwsgi with flask with multiple workers and run them as service "systemctl" and here is the **mywebsite.ini** file for it. But as far as I know uwsgi does not cache by default.

```
[uwsgi]
module = application:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = mywebsite.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
enable-threads = true
die-on-term = true
```

### UPDATE 05/03/2019

The issue is with uWSGI processes and not Nginx. When I changed them to 0 in **mywebsite.ini** it works fine without incorrect old data being returned. But I still want multiple processes for better performance!! any idea how?

Comment: Most of your Nginx configuration is contained within included files: `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf`, `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`, and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`.

Comment: So where is the issue in that?

Comment: Your question suggests that Nginx is the problem, but does not contain any relevant configuration files.

Comment: I have a mydomain.com file in sites-available and linked with sites-enabled but it only contains config to point to the server Flask.